# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 292-293: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape during import

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Code:

```
import os
import random
import time
import requests
from appetizer import Appetizer
```

Result:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/GITHUB/stress_testing/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from appetizer import Appetizer
  File "C:\GITHUB\stress_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\appetizer\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .appetizer import Appetizer
  File "C:\GITHUB\stress_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\appetizer\appetizer.py", line 76
            """
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 292-293: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

76 line in appetizer.py file:

```
 def detect_adb(self):
        """ Detect the path to the adb tool from the Android SDK

        :return: A JSON object. For example: {'adb': '/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'}

        Note that the path could be a unicode string.
        The default installation paths for different OSes are:
        Windows: C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
        Linux: /home/<User Name>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
        """
        return json.loads(self.appetizer.check_output(["adb", "detectadb"]))
```

I know about "\" (double "\" in the path for Windows), "/" and so on. But here I have error BEFORE I done someting - on the import stage. What should I change and where?
I tried with virtual env and common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually tells you what is wrong. There is a \uxxxxxxx escaped character with an invalid length at position 292-293 in your function definition in line 76 of your code.

The following will work:

```
stri = """ Detect the path to the adb tool from the Android SDK

    :return: A JSON object. For example: {'adb': '/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'}

    Note that the path could be a unicode string.
    The default installation paths for different OSes are:
    Windows: C:\\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
    Linux: /home/<User Name>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
    """
stri[292] #'\\'
stri[293] #'U'
```

Whereas:

```
stri = """ Detect the path to the adb tool from the Android SDK

    :return: A JSON object. For example: {'adb': '/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'}

    Note that the path could be a unicode string.
    The default installation paths for different OSes are:
    Windows: C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
    Linux: /home/<User Name>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
    """
#SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 292-293: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

The reason for this behaviour is that (please indicate the relevant package next time) [replay-kit](https://github.com/appetizerio/replaykit/tree/master/win32) is written for Python 2.7, where the `'\U'` would pass without a hitch. You'll have to check the source code and replace such sequences with a double backslash or forward slash manually.